# which execution plan has better performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

(my english is not good enough. so bear with me)

I am working on optimizing this query:

```
Select Title from Groups Where GroupID = WWPMD.GroupID) as GroupName 
FROM         dbo.Detail AS WWPMD INNER JOIN
                  dbo.News AS WWPMN ON WWPMD.DetailID = WWPMN.NewsID
WHERE 
WWPMD.IsDeleted = 0 AND WWPMD.IsEnabled= 1 AND WWPMD.GroupID IN (
Select ModuleID FROM Page_Content_Item WHERE     ContentID='a6780e80-4ead4e62-9b22-1190bb88ed90')
```

in this case, tables have clustered indexes on primary keys which are GUID. in the execution plan, the arrows were a little thick, and the cost of clustered index seek, for table "detail" was 87%, and there was no cost for key lookup

then, I changed indexes of table "detail". I have put clustered index on a datetime column, and 3 unclustered indexes on PK and FKs. now in the execution plan, index seek cost for table detail is 4percent and key lookup is 80 percent, with thin arrows.

I want to know which execution plan is better, and what can I do to improve this query.

**UPDATE:**

thank all of you for your guidance. one more question. I want to know if 80% cost of a clustered index seek is better, or 80% total cost of a non-clustered index seek and key look up. which one is better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read an execution plan in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-an-execution-plan-in-sql-server)

Comment: For comparing plan, the best single statistic to look at is TotalSubtreeCost -- the actual number is meaningless, but you can "compare" plans that way. A Bigger cost means more costly to perform (slower)

Comment: Your query have wrong format.

Comment: 80% key look up cost is better, or 80%  clustered index seek?

Comment: to answer to my own question, I have learned that key look up occurs when optimizer can't obtain all the needed data with a non-clustered index seek and needs to seek from clustered index. it is not good for the performance. with included index we can eliminate this operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN  statement is good for selecting littele bit data if you are selecting more data you should use INNER JOIN its better performance than IN  for large data

IN is faster than JOIN on DISTINCT

EXISTS is more efficient that IN, because "EXISTS returns only one row"

Comment: I can't use inner join, because tables "content-Item" and "detail" are not related. is it better if I use EXISTS?

Comment: EXISTS is always better than IN statement use it

Comment: actually, all the answeres helped me somehow. there is not a particular correct one. some helped me more, but unfortunatly because I'm a new member and I don't have enough reputation, I can't vote.

Answer (score 0):

Clustered index on a guid column is not a good idea when your guids are not sequential, since this will lead to performance loss on inserts. The records in your table are physically ordered based on the clustered index. The clustered index should be put on a column wich has sequential values and doesn't change (often).

if you have a nonclustered index on groupid (table groups), then you could make 'title' an included column on that index. See msdn for included columns.

Comment: I have removed clustered index from PK(GUID) and I've put it on a column named "creation time" with timedate format. but I don't use that column in this query. please tell me your opinion about this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use following query:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ModuleID FROM Page_Content_Item WHERE ContentID='a6780e80-4ead4e62-9b22-1190bb88ed90')z OR WWPMD.GroupID= z.ModuleID
```

Instead of:

```
AND WWPMD.GroupID IN (
   Select ModuleID FROM Page_Content_Item WHERE ContentID='a6780e80-4ead4e62-9b22-1190bb88ed90')
```

Also must be survey execution plan of this query, It seem that Index on `Detail.DetailId` with filter (`IsDeleted = 0 and IsEnable = 1`) was very useful.

Comment: You use `)` before of `as GroupName`, and don't exists '(' before this.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes will not be particularly useful unless the leftmost indexed columns are specified in JOIN and/or WHERE clauses.  I suggest thise indexes below (unique when possible): dbo.Detail(GroupID), dbo.News(DetailID), dbo.Page_Content_Item(ContentID)

You can fine tine these indexes with included columns and/or filters, but I suspect performance may be good enough without those measures.

Note that primary keys are important.  Not only is that a design best practice, a unique index will automatically be created on the key columns(s), which can improve performance of joins to the table on related columns.  Consider reviewing your model to ensure you have proper primary keys and relationships.